# C# pass DateTime type data controller to webapi service method issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, datetime-format

I tried to pass DateTime type data from controllers methods parameter to webapi services method, but reaching dtetime data in webapi service its completely different. For example :

```
//in my Test.controller:

public getUsersFromDateInfo(DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate)
{
     DateTime startdate = startDate== null ? DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-12) : startDate.Value;
     DateTime enddate = endDate== null ? DateTime.UtcNow : endDate.Value;
     
     var subInfoUsers = _iTestService.getUsersDetails( 
     new userDateilRequest{
     uStartDate=startdate, 
     uEndDate =enddate
     }
     );
}


//My api service is:

public UserDetailResponse getUsersDetails(userDateilRequest request)
 {
   //do something
 }

//My Object class is:

public class userDateilRequest 
{
   public DateTime uStartDate{ get; set; }
   public DateTime uEndDate { get; set; }
}
```

But, userDateilRequest parameters
in controller like this:
uStartDate= {1.12.2020 00:00:00}
uEndDate = {31.12.2020 00:00:00}

in service like this:
uStartDate= {30.11.2020 21:00:00}
uEndDate = {30.12.2020 21:00:00}

I dont know why change like that

Comment: You have no `enddate`, only `endDate` and `endate`.

Comment: Sorry for lacking explanation for my issue, but now I added more detail @Gustav

Comment: Aside from anything else, I'd *strongly* encourage you to start following .NET naming conventions, and pay more attention to detail to avoid typos - `userDateilRequest ` should be `UserDetailRequest` for example. Code with typos in names and unconventional naming (e.g. in terms of capitalization and the "u" prefix you've got for properties in the request class) is much harder to read.

Comment: I wouldn't expect this code to compile at the moment, mind you: `uEndDate =enddate` appears to use a variable `enddate` which isn't declared anywhere. (You've got `endate` and `endDate`, neither of which is the same as `enddate`.)

Comment: Actually enddate defined at the beginning of method. this is : DateTime enddate = endDate== null ? DateTime.UtcNow : endDate.Value; ,Also thanks for your advice @JonSkeet

Comment: @hkyaaa: Only because you edited it after I'd commented... that's a pretty disingenuous comment, implying that I'd just missed the declaration - when I specifically listed the variables you *had* declared. Likewise an edit comment of "improved format" is disingenuous when it was really "fix the variable name declaration". Changing a variable name is *not* formatting.

Comment: Sorry man, I actually dont know editted ordering also I think you will see this changes and everything normal. @JonSkeet

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I actually dont know editted ordering" but you made the edit to fix the variable name *30 seconds* before adding the comment... so it seems pretty likely that the edit was to respond to my comment. Again, implying that my comment was mistaken is not appropriate. Even with the change, we're basically missing a [mcve]. We don't know how your service is configured at all... my *guess* is that this is an issue with daylight saving time being applied, but it's hard to say with so little detail.

Comment: Looks like when user is accessing you controller it creates user specific culture. Try to pass date to your api in format 2020-11-30T21:00:00.000Z to see what is happening.